# A Question dealing with second order interpolating polynomials that must go through two specific points

Tags: statistics

Below is  problem I made up. I think I did it right but I could not verify my answer using R. If asked, I would be happy to post my R script.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
Given the points $(0,0), (1,3), (2,5), (3,7), (4,4)$ find a second order
interpolating polynomial, of the form $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$, such that the points $0,0)$ and $(4,4)$ are on the curve and the following is minimized:
$$  (f(1) -3)^2 + (f(2) - 5)^2 +( f(3) - 7)^2  $$
Answer: 
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= A(0^2) + B(0) + C = 0 \\
C &= 0 \\
f(4) &= A(4^2) + B(4) = 4 \\
4 &= 16A + 4B \\
1 &= 4A + B \\
B &= 1 - 4A \\
f(x) &= Ax^2 + (1 - 4A)X \\
\end{align*}
Let $D = (f(1) -3)^2 + (f(2) - 5)^2 +( f(3) - 7)^2$. We need to find a value of $A$ such that $D$ is
minimized.
\begin{align*}
D &= (A+(1 - 4A) -3)^2 + (4A+2(1 - 4A) - 5)^2 +( 9A + 4(1 - 4A) - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (4A+ 2- 8A - 5)^2 +( 9A + 4 - 16A - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (-4A - 3)^2 + ( -7A - 3)^2 \\
D &= ( 3A + 2)^2 + (4A + 3)^2 + ( 7A + 3 )^2 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 2(3)(3A+2) + 2(4)(4A+3) + 2(7)(7A + 3 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 6(3A+2) + 8(4A+3) + 14(7A + 3 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 18A + 12 + 32A + 24 + 98A + 42 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 50A + 98A + 78 = 148A + 78 \\
\end{align*}
Now to find the value of $A$ that minimizes $D$ we set $\frac{dD}{dA} = 0$.
\begin{align*}
148A + 78 &= 0 \\
A &= -\frac{78}{148} = -\frac{39}{74} \\
B &= 1 - 4\left(  -\frac{39}{74} \right) = 1 + \frac{(4)39}{74} \\
B &= 1 + \frac{2(39)}{37} \\
B &= \frac{115}{37} \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ f(x) = \left( -\frac{39}{74} \right)x^2 - \left(  \frac{115}{37} \right)x $$
Using the program R, I find that:
$$ f(x) = -0.8824x^2 +  4.529x -4.144e-13 $$
I am wondering what I did wrong.

Based upon the comments from the group, I updated my answer. However, it is still wrong. Here is the updated answer.

\newline
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= A(0^2) + B(0) + C = 0 \\
C &= 0 \\
f(4) &= A(4^2) + B(4) = 4 \\
4 &= 16A + 4B \\
1 &= 4A + B \\
B &= 1 - 4A \\
f(x) &= Ax^2 + (1 - 4A)X \\
\end{align*}
Let $D = (f(1) -3)^2 + (f(2) - 5)^2 +( f(3) - 7)^2$. We need to find a value of $A$ such that $D$ is
minimized.
\begin{align*}
D &= (A+(1 - 4A) -3)^2 + (4A+2(1 - 4A) - 5)^2 +( 9A + 3(1 - 4A) - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (4A+ 2- 8A - 5)^2 +( 9A + 3 - 16A - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (-4A - 3)^2 + ( -7A - 4)^2 \\
D &= ( 3A + 2)^2 + (4A + 3)^2 + ( 7A + 4 )^2 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 2(3)(3A+2) + 2(4)(4A+3) + 2(7)(7A + 4 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 6(3A+2) + 8(4A+3) + 14(7A + 4 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 18A + 12 + 32A + 24 + 98A + 56 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 50A + 98A + 88 = 148A + 88 \\
\end{align*}
Now to find the value of $A$ that minimizes $D$ we set $\frac{dD}{dA} = 0$.
\begin{align*}
148A + 88 &= 0 \\
A &= -\frac{88}{148} = -\frac{22}{37} \\
B &= 1 - 4\left(  -\frac{22}{37} \right) = 1 + \frac{(4)22}{37} \\
B &= 1 + \frac{88}{37}
B &= \frac{125}{37} \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ f(x) = -\left( \frac{22}{37} \right)x^2 + \left( \frac{125}{37} \right)x $$
We can rewrite this using decimal numbers.
$$ f(x) = 0.385135135x^2 - 0.540540541x $$
Using the program R, I find that:
$$ f(x) = -0.8824x^2 +  4.529x -4.144e-13 $$
I am wondering what I did wrong.

I fixed an algebra error and here is a correct solution:

\begin{align*}
f(0) &= A(0^2) + B(0) + C = 0 \\
C &= 0 \\
f(4) &= A(4^2) + B(4) = 4 \\
4 &= 16A + 4B \\
1 &= 4A + B \\
B &= 1 - 4A \\
f(x) &= Ax^2 + (1 - 4A)X \\
\end{align*}
Let $D = (f(1) -3)^2 + (f(2) - 5)^2 +( f(3) - 7)^2$. We need to find a value of $A$ such that $D$ is
minimized.
\begin{align*}
D &= (A+(1 - 4A) -3)^2 + (4A+2(1 - 4A) - 5)^2 +( 9A + 3(1 - 4A) - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (4A+ 2- 8A - 5)^2 +( 9A + 3 - 12A - 7)^2 \\
D &= (-3A  -2)^2 + (-4A - 3)^2 + ( -3A - 4)^2 \\
D &= ( 3A + 2)^2 + (4A + 3)^2 + ( 3A + 4 )^2 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 2(3)(3A+2) + 2(4)(4A+3) + 2(3)(3A + 4 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 6(3A+2) + 8(4A+3) + 6(3A + 4 ) \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 18A + 12 + 32A + 24 + 18A + 24 \\
\frac{dD}{dA} &= 68A + 60 \\
\end{align*}
Now to find the value of $A$ that minimizes $D$ we set $\frac{dD}{dA} = 0$.
\begin{align*}
68A + 60 &= 0 \\
17A + 15 &= 0 \\
A &= -\frac{15}{17} \\
B &= 1 - 4\left(  -\frac{15}{17} \right) = 1 + \frac{60}{77} \\
B &= 1 + \frac{88}{37}
B &= \frac{77}{17} \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ f(x) = -\left( \frac{15}{17} \right)x^2 + \left( \frac{77}{17} \right)x $$
Using the program R, I find that:
$$ f(x) = -0.8824x^2 +  4.529x -4.144e-13 $$
The answer's match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line after "We need to find a value of $A$ such that $D$ is minimized," the last term should be $(9A+\color{red}{3}(1−4A)−7)^2.$